# how to get DisplayMemeber value from listbox by valuemember c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listBox, something like this:

ID ClientName

1. Michael
2. Steve
3. Smith

Now, I know the ID of the client , how do i get the DisplayMember of it ?

Comment: What do you mean by `DisplayMember` of client? You can get name of property used for displaying in listbox by `listBox.DisplayMember`

Comment: What I ment is, if i know that the client id is 1, i need to know that his name is Michael

Comment: What data your listbox is bound to? Is it list of Client objects?

Answer (score 1):

Cast into `DataRowView` and convert select the client name column by index, which is 1.

```
String ClientName = (((DataRowView) listBox1.SelectedItem).Row[1]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code. the example is written if the `DataSource` of the `Listbox` is `DataTable`, but if it is something else, try to see of what type is the `object` in Items property of the `ListBox`.

(Note that I don't like using `break` statement but this was the quickest way)

```
string str = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRowView drv in listBox1.Items)
{
       int lvID = int.Parse(drv.Row[listBox1.ValueMember].ToString());
       if (lvID == 5)
       {
             str = drv.Row[listBox1.DisplayMember].ToString();
             break;
       }
}
```

Comment: Why do i have to look at all items in the list , if i know the valueMember . if it is a 1000 items listt, i have to check all 1000 items ?

Comment: @user1205025 Have you found any better way? Why don't you instead search in your DataSource instance, I would rather do that. In ListBox you should select some data, it shouldn't be used as a data structure for holding data.

Comment: @user1205025 In addition to this, if there is any other method it also iterates (possibly with some optimisations) but it is hidden from you.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic if i use DataSource of the listbox is list then how can i get Selected values can you please help me

Comment: @Siva I really don't understand your question, could you please be more clear so I could try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = from list in USStates where te.ShortName == textBox1.Text select te.LongName.ToString();     

foreach(String st in t)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(st);   
}
```

where USStates is Generic List and TextBox1.text contains the value of the id.Considering your listbox uses Generic list as DataSource.

Comment: what is list , te in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier solution. Especially if you are building the DataSource, populating it, then releasing the source. Use the Items list to create a DataRowView of the item currently selected. Then just pull the right index. 0 will give you the "value member" and 1 will give you the "display member".

```
DataRowView thisLine = cbTrackerFormList.Items[cbTrackerFormList.SelectedIndex] as DataRowView;
```